# Se muestra en blanco la parte de diseño de Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: java, android, diseño

tengo un problema con el diseñador de interfaz de android studio
siempre se muestra en blanco sin importar los elementos que le ponga no se ve nada como se muestra en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya he intentado limpiar el proyecto y reconstruirlo y aun así no funciona espero que alguien me pueda ayudar estoy utilizando Android Studio 3.1.3
Cabe mencionar que cuando lo pruebo si se ven los componentes pero resulta muy poco práctico poner la interfaz sin la ayuda visual

Comment: pulsa el icono rojo de precaución, para ver que incidencia obtienes

Comment: Cuál es el SDK min al que va dirigida tu app?

Comment: A la v5 y lo que indica es lo siguiente

Comment: Prueba a bajar el nivel del SDK de preview (la pestaña entre dispositivo -en tu caso tienes en la imagen "Nexus 7", y la pestaña del tema), a mi muchas veces me funciona de esta manera. Si lo tienes en 28, prueba en 27, y así sucesivamente, normalmente vas a poder ver tu vista de esta manera.

Comment: Si en tu graddle tienes una versión mínima de android, por ejemplo la 22, baja hasta esa en la interfaz gráfica (muñeco verde).

Answer (score 0):

Hola a todos encontré la solución y es editar esta linea del gradle
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

Y dejarla como se muestra a continuación 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

Y eso es todo se soluciono el problema